# How to fix "Test Class not found in selected project" in cucumber junit

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, cucumber-junit

I am new to Cucumber. I created a simple cucumber script to launch google in browser. I properly created features, steps and runner classes. When I ran the runner class, the junit result shows green but the scenario not executed (browser not launched). On checking the results and trying to double-click, it says "Test Class not found in selected project".

I already tried changing order of JRE in Build path->Order&Export option. This is Eclipse.[JUnit result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4php.jpg)

This is the runner class:

```java
package Runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="Features/ChromeTest.feature",glue= {"src/test/java/Steps"})
public class ChromeRunner {

}
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782803/test-class-not-found-in-selected-project#31022284.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you keep your features files also within src/test/java path

if so,please try running with

> @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",glue="steps")

or

> @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",glue="src/test/java/steps")

**assuming that you have created features and steps as package inside src/test/java path

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my Features folder is Outside src folder. So I hope there is no issue with folder structure. Is there anything to check with dependencies (its a maven). Kindly clarify

Comment: Can you try working with below framework https://github.com/toolsqa/CucumberFramework